# Elements Disappear on DIV Refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

For some reason, the elements that are supposed to be loaded using this code into certain DIVs disappear when I call a refresh of the DIV explicitly.  If I refresh the ENTIRE page the elements will return of course.  What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
(function() {
$('div.heriyah').each(function() { 
$(this).html('<? if (!isset($_SESSION[\'username2009\'])) {} else { echo \"<div class=\"add\"><div id=\"add_button_container\"><div id=\"add_button\" class=\"edit_links\">  + Add Element</div></div></div><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>\"; }?>');

 var curID = $(this).attr('id');//get the id before you go into fallr

$('.add').click(function() {
$.fallr('show', {
          content     :  '<iframe width="620" height="600" src="admin/add_content_select.php?pageID=<? echo $pageID; ?>&div='+ curID +'"></iframe>',
          width       : 320, // 100 = for width padding
          height         : 400,
              closeKey        : true,
              closeOverlay    : true,
              buttons     : {}
    }); 
    }); 

    }); 
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in `$_SESSION`.

```
'<? if (!isset($_SESSION[\'username2009\'])) ... '
                     //  ^             ^
```

You also have some more escaping issues with this part:

```
echo \"<div class=\"add\"><div id=\"add_button_container\"><div id=\"add_button\" class=\"edit_links\">  + Add Element</div></div></div><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>\";
```

When this is evaluated, it will look like this:

```
echo "<div class="add"><div id="add_button_container"><div id="add_button" class="edit_links">  + Add Element</div></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>";
```

This is not valid and to fix it, you need to add a backslash before each escaped quote.

```
echo \"<div class=\\\"add\\\"><div id=\\\"add_button_container\\\"><div id=\\\"add_button\\\" class=\\\"edit_links\\\">  + Add Element</div></div></div><div class=\\\"clear\\\"></div></div>\";
```

Comment: ahhh, you are the best.  I've been working on escaping quotes for the past two days.  I missed this one!  Thanks!  Let me try it out!

Comment: hmmm, there is something else that needs to be done, because the ending `?>` isn't getting called.  IF I don't escape the quotes like above it will show up, but I know I need to escape.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have some more escaping issues. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am still having trouble with the `$_SESSION` part.  I have changed everything accordingly and now all the PHP variables are showing up properly, but session still doesn't look right in Dreamweaver.  The two backslashes before `username2009` and the two after `echo` are showing up black instead of red.  Here's what I have `$(this).html('<? if (isset($_SESSION[\\'username2009\\'])) { echo \\"<div class=\\\"add\\\"><div id=\\\"add_button_container\\\"><div id=\\\"add_button\\\" class=\\\"edit_links\\\">  + Add Element</div></div></div><div class=\\\"clear\\\"></div></div>\\"; }?>');`

Comment: Try this: `$(this).html('<? if (isset($_SESSION[\'username2009\'])) { echo \"<div class=\\\"add\\\"><div id=\\\"add_button_container\\\"><div id=\\\"add_button\\\" class=\\\"edit_links\\\"> + Add Element</div></div></div><div class=\\\"clear\\\"></div></div>\"; }?>');`

Comment: That makes it worse!  It's still that first backslash.  Maybe I need to go a different route, but I only want this to show when the session is set.

Comment: Why not just make an Ajax call to your server and check. I don't think you can set the HTML of an element as PHP, because PHP is executed on the server side.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking that myself!  I am kicking myself because I feel stupid now!  Sorry for wasting your time with this bro, but I do appreciate your time!